# Why does visibility change before/after nested fragment insertion

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

I'm trying to resolve a larger problem that relates to animating a nested fragment so I created a separate project and am trying to tackle it in modules.

The first part is toggling visibility within the `childFragment` - I've been trying different types of code and I'm not sure why when I add `layoutReturn.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);`

[image: After adding the child fragment, the parent fragment remains]

The parent fragment is hidden. Yet when I add this line after inserting the child fragment:

```
 @Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    //layoutReturn.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    FragmentManager childFrag = getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction childFragTrans = childFrag.beginTransaction();
    addressCard_fragment addressCardChild = new addressCard_fragment();
    childFragTrans.add(R.id.bottom_row_fragment_container, addressCardChild);
    //childFragTrans.setCustomAnimations(R.animator.slide_in_card, R.animator.slide_out_card);
    childFragTrans.commit();
    Toast.makeText(getActivity().getBaseContext(), "yo", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    layoutReturn.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);


}
```

The change has no effect. The parent fragment remains visible, the Toast appears but the `childFragment` remains unseen. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Main Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private topRow_fragment fragmentTopRow;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        fragmentTopRow = new topRow_fragment();
    }

    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.top_row_fragment_container, fragmentTopRow);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
}}
```

parentFragment class:

```
public class topRow_fragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener{

ImageButton btn;
View layoutReturn;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    layoutReturn = inflater.inflate(R.layout.firstrow_fragment, container, false);

    btn = (ImageButton) layoutReturn.findViewById(R.id.imageLeft);
    btn.setOnClickListener(this);

    return layoutReturn;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    //layoutReturn.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    FragmentManager childFrag = getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction childFragTrans = childFrag.beginTransaction();
    addressCard_fragment addressCardChild = new addressCard_fragment();
    childFragTrans.add(R.id.bottom_row_fragment_container, addressCardChild);
    //childFragTrans.setCustomAnimations(R.animator.slide_in_card, R.animator.slide_out_card);
    childFragTrans.commit();
    Toast.makeText(getActivity().getBaseContext(), "yo", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    layoutReturn.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);


}}
```

childFragment class is just the typical onCreateView method.

Update01: When I use getChildFragmentManager I receive a massive error that begins with `09-14 22:54:34.933 20795-20795/com.example.bryanjordan.nestedfragmentstest E/FragmentManager: No view found for id 0x7f0c0060 (com.example.bryanjordan.nestedfragmentstest:id/bottom_row_fragment_container) for fragment addressCard_fragment{7d09836 #0 id=0x7f0c0060}`

and is summarised with: `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f0c0060 (com.example.bryanjordan.nestedfragmentstest:id/bottom_row_fragment_container) for fragment addressCard_fragment{7d09836 #0 id=0x7f0c0060}`

**XML files:**

Main Activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
tools:context="com.example.bryanjordan.nestedfragmentstest.MainActivity">

<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="368dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="8dp"
        android:id="@+id/constraintLayout"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/top_row_fragment_container"
            android:layout_width="367dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="8dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="1dp">
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/bottom_row_fragment_container"
            android:layout_width="367dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="8dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="1dp">
        </RelativeLayout>



    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/constraintLayout"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/second_Row_container"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="25dp">

        </RelativeLayout>
    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**firstrow_fragment**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/parent_row_container"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
tools:context="com.example.bryanjordan.nestedfragmentstest.MainActivity">

<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/cardTop"
        android:layout_width="340dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
        android:elevation="5dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
        app:contentPadding="5dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_goneMarginLeft="5dp"
        app:layout_goneMarginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp">

        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:paddingRight="5dp">

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/imageLeft"
                android:layout_width="60dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:background="@drawable/square"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageCentre"
                android:layout_width="60dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="13dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="13dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:background="@drawable/square"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/imageLeft"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageRight"
                android:layout_width="60dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="13dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="13dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:background="@drawable/square"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/imageCentre"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>


    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**addressCard**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/address_card_container"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
tools:context="com.example.bryanjordan.nestedfragmentstest.MainActivity">

<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/years_of_cooking_xp_cardView"
        android:layout_width="337dp"
        android:layout_height="240dp"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:elevation="50dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
        app:contentPadding="5dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_goneMarginLeft="5dp"
        app:layout_goneMarginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="20dp">
        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:paddingRight="5dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:text="Test"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/experience_left_button"
                android:layout_width="60dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:background="@drawable/square"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/experience_centre_button"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/experience_centre_button"
                android:layout_width="60dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:background="@drawable/square"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/experience_right_button"
                android:layout_width="60dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:background="@drawable/square"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/experience_centre_button"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/zero_to_one_Year"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:text="0 - 1 Year"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/experience_left_button"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/experience_left_button"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/experience_left_button"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/experience_left_button" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/one_to_three_years"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="1 - 3 Years"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/experience_centre_button"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/experience_centre_button"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/experience_centre_button"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/experience_centre_button"
                />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/three_plus_years"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="3+ Years"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/experience_right_button"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/experience_right_button"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/experience_right_button"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/experience_right_button"
                />

        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>


    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both your `top_row_fragment_container` and `bottom_row_fragment_container` containers are in **MainActivity**. Then it is not prbably nested fragment.

Nested fragment mean **Fragment** inside **Fragment**.

You have wrap_content as container height.

```
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

Set some height to get both of your fragment visible.

Remove `layoutReturn.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);` from your code.

Comment: I was using getChildFragmentManager() originally but kept facing a very big error - I'll include the error report in the post.

Comment: can you post your **topRow_fragment** XML

Comment: @Hews bottom_row_fragment_container is RelativeLayout Please FrameLayout instead of RelativeLayout

Comment: @Hews One more thing your bottom_row_fragment_container is in main activity layout not in xml layout file of topRow_fragment

Comment: @Hews See my updated answer. Set height for your both containers

Comment: @JRamesh I changed bottom_row_fragment_container in activity_main.xml  and there's no changes. I'll add a photo.

Comment: @Hews also use frame layout instead of the Relative layout. That is recommended

Comment: @BhuvaneshBs do you mean I should include a Frame Layout in the parent fragment? So I should move bottom_row_fragment_container into firstrow_fragment XML file? 

Re container height: to confirm, I should use a definitive value like a hard-coded one?

Comment: Leave it as Relative layout for now. I have updated my answer. Remove the line layoutReturn.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE) in your onclick

Answer (score 1):

**Solution**

Firstly, thanks to Bhuvanesh Bs and JRamesh for their help.

For those facing a similar issue I'd recommend quickly considering the following:

1. Ensure you're initialising your child fragment within another Fragment. While Bhuvanesh recommended not to move a FrameLayout into the parent fragment, I found this worked. Unfortunately the child fragment was now being initialised in the CardView of the parent fragment.
2. Toggling visibility was resolved by referencing the container of the child fragment that was the `FrameLayout` added to the parent fragment as noted in point 1.
3. With respect to toggling the visibility of `layoutReturn` I think this was because I was returning `layoutReturn` without updating any changes. This explains why without any additions, the activity would turn blank. However, once adding the new fragment, the layout changes and so changing the visibility of the layout is a now out-dated call. Should be noted, I'm not confident with this answer so please take it with a grain of salt.

Cheers